# secret_token and secret_key_base not being found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, secret-key

I have not touched my code in about two weeks and everything was working. Upon trying to run the server, I kept seeing an Internal Server Error with the following message:

Missing `secret_token` and `secret_key_base` for 'development' environment, set these values in `config/secrets.yml`

and in my server log:

`DEPRECATION WARNING: You didn't set secret_key_base. Read the upgrade documentation to learn more about this new config option. (called from service at /Users/anishasrivastava/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138)`

This is my secrets.yml file: 

`development:
secret_token: (random sequence generated with rake secret)
secret_key_base: (random sequence generated with rake secret)`


`test:
  secret_token: (random sequence generated with rake secret)
  secret_key_base: (random sequence generated with rake secret)`


`production:
  secret_key_base: <%= ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE"] %>`

So, the values seem to be clearly in the secrets.yml file. I have never seen this error before and have not changed anything

Comment: do you see something in console `Rails.application.secrets`

Comment: I'm not sure if you correctly pasted `secrets.yml`, but there is missing indentation before `secret_token` and `secret_key_base` in the `development` section.

Comment: @OlegSobchuk 
Hi, this was my server log when I tried that command:

`projects/applications/lightpath  master ✗    
                                                    
▶ Rails.application.secrets

zsh: command not found: Rails.application.secrets
`

Comment: @Mareq, hello. I pasted it incorrectly - there is indentation.

Comment: When I search this in irb a value is returned: 
`2.2.3 :001 > ENV['SECRET_KEY_BASE']`
 `=> `

`"087f32abe80ff0fba4381efddc7b118431d5b495177401da6022975db7f6c113c7f73bf53e4cd08ec996667e5725d04bc6ba799ec495db1cd8b28fbfcd19ce54"`